# Get user ID from CSRF token

Tags: 7, users, csrf

Is there any way how can I programmatically get user ID from CSRF token?
I'm using web service and need to update user data according to user token.

Comment: Who is generating the token ?

Comment: token is generated by Drupal and i can see it when user visit website.com/api/user/token

Comment: How, or which module, is genarating the token.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a view with contextual filter CSRF and field UID.
2. Get the view programmatically

   $view_object = views_get_view("view_name");

Then we set the view display that we want to process.

```
$view_object->set_display("my_display");
```

Other methods can be used to customize the we way the view will be processed like set_items_per_page or set_arguments... A full reference of these methods can be found here: https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/class/view/7. You have to use the set_arguments to add the CRSF key as a contextual reference to the view

Before processing the view using the execute method, it's recommended to run the pre_execute method.

```
$view_object->pre_execute();
$view_object->execute();
```

The results of the processed view are stored in the result property

```
$results = $view_object->result;
```

If you need the rendered results, you can go further and render the view.

```
$output = $view_object->render();
print $output;
```

Thxs to reference:
https://blog.cloudtroopers.com/programmatically-fetch-results-view-drupal-7

Comment: What are you doing!?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using `global $user;` and then I don't need to use access token from session, just `$user->uid;`

Thanks anyway